# Gitlab runner cant perform git command

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd, runner

I’ve facing this problem for the CI/CD pipeline, it always failed in git command resulting error of

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at ‘/home/adadev/docker_folder//…’
```

I’ve tried adding **safe.directory “*”** in the runner env and some git command finally able to run (such as, git branch)

But the problem still remains when im about to **git stash**. The job just forced ended without any error log/ traces even if I see the full raw

```
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables00:00

[39](https://repo.polytron.co.id/ADA/commercial/digitec-tv/-/jobs/5826#L39)ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Gitlab runner version : **16.1.0**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH0wp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSvN9.jpg)

**Updates:**

- I tried running gitlab-runner in debug mode and using command `sudo gitlab-runner --debug run`
- its working and the CI build success
- when I stop and try to run `sudo gitlab-runner start` the job keep failing again